# tmuxinator specify custom project config file

Tags: git, shell, terminal, tmux, tmuxinator

I'm trying to store my tmuxinator project config in a file in my actual repo with all the other config files rather than the normal place it stores them all.

But i can't see a way to load tmuxinator from a config file with any flags etc.
I know that i can create a project config with `tmuxinator new [name]` and then it stores it as `~/.tmuxinator/[name].yml` but i'd like to have this file in my repo.

Would a good solution be to just create a symbolic link between the files?

Or would this be bad practice with tmuxinator? If so why?

Thanks in advance.

---

[edit]

For now, I've created a task in my makefile to create a link with:

```
link-tmuxinator: 
    @mkdir -p ~/.tmuxinator/
    ln ${projectpath}/tmuxinator.yml ~/.tmuxinator/${projectname}.yml
```

Works well for now, runs once on setup, let me know though if you have any other ideas for future projects though.

Comment: Not an answer, the goal will be to support this in 0.7.0. Ongoing development is here: https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator/pull/123

Comment: Thanks @Soliah, the new stuff on the list for 0.7.0 looks great!